# Using S3 as a fallback with nginx fails on first "few" loads

Tags: wordpress, nginx, amazon-s3

I have a wordpress site on a multi-server setup (EC2), and I move all image uploads to S3. I have set up nginx this way to redirect image requests to S3:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Pragma public;

    error_page 404 = @s3blog;
}

location @s3blog {
    proxy_buffering        on;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;

    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass $scheme://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com;
}
```

This only works after the first load of the page. I get complaints very frequently from the people in charge of the blog that there are broken images. When I check it out it's fine but that first load doesn't work. The server uses fastcgi for `location ~ .php$`.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please define "doesn't work" a little more clearly... what do you see in the nginx logs? What response to you get if you use curl for that first request?

Comment: sorry @Michael-sqlbot for the late reply. So I tried on one image I had never hit and got 3 400 errors, then all good, 200 all the way.

Comment: Looked at the logs and non bots get a "bunch" of 400s before it starts becoming a 200, bots show a 404 (like YandexImage). The thing is after a while the images becomes a 400 again, and there's a couple of 400s until 200 appears again…

Comment: Were you able to capture a response body with maybe some xml in it on the 400 errors?  If nginx is keeping persistent connections to S3 alive for too long, they will return a 400 instead of the more correct 408, but there should be a response body included ... you should set `proxy_intercept_errors` `off` so you can read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding error_page 400 = @s3blog; above the 404 one.